# How to fetch many-to-many relationship entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have following table structure

```
TABLE1
  T1_ID
  T1_Col1

TABLE2
  T1_ID
  T3_ID

TABLE3
  T3_ID
  T3_COL1
```

`Table1` and `Table3` are joined by a middle table which is `Table2`. Now I have only `T1_ID` and I want to fetch all the rows from `Table3` which are associated with `T1_ID`. A simple SQL query would be

```
select T1.*, T3.* 
from TABLE1 T1, TABLE T2, TABLE3 T3
where T1.T1_ID = T2.T1_ID
and T2.T3_ID = T3.T3_ID
```

So how can i do this in hibernate/jpa ... I have yet to write my entity classes for `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`. I want to execute this query as part of `Table1`, so that i can write a method say `entity.fetchAssociatedTable3()`. The easiest approach i can think of is in `fetchAssociatedTable3` i can put custom queries like the one i mentioned above. But since i am using hibernate/jpa I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

**UPDATE**
Apparently, my question isn't clear enough. I want to do something as user Dragan Bozanovic mentioned. However, What i want to know that

1. How would i write `Table1` entity ? I mean what annotations i would put on the columns etc which will make hibernate/jpa understand that this column is related to `Table3` column via `Table2`
2. I guess if question 1 is answered, then it would be difficult to write `getEntity3s()` method. But if (for a noob) there is something that I need to know, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will have a many-to-many association between `Entity1` (mapped to `TABLE1`) and `Entity3` (mapped to `TABLE3`), you can either:

1) read the `Entity1` by id and get all of the `Entity3`s from it:

```
Entity1 entity1 = entityManager.find(Entity1.class, entity1Id);
Collection<Entity3> entity3s = entity1.getEntity3s();
```

2) or, execute the JPQL query to get `Entity3`s without loading the `Entity1` instance:

```
select distinct e3 from Entity3 e3 join Entity1 e1 where e1.id = :entity1Id
```

Comment: thats what i want to do. but my questions are **1: how would i write getEntity3s() method** ... **2: how would i write the entity1 class? how would i put the mappining, joining details etc?**

Comment: It's a broad topic to be covered in an answer. You should go through a Hibernate/JPA tutorial or a book.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you would need do is to stop thinking in terms of tables when using ORM tool (Hibernate/JPA). You model your classes and their relations and let the ORM tool help with the mappings declaratively. Your join table just is serving here for creating relation many to many relation between two entities. So in terms of classes you would have only Entity1 and Entity3. You would not be creating a class representing join table (unless of course you want it to have other attributes other than foreign keys in which case it would qualify to be a Entity class in it's own right). And then you can use either method suggested by @Dragan i.e., loading by primary key or using explicit HQL/JPQL.

Comment: He wanted to know how to handle the situation, and not how to use an orm. He could have inherited legacy code, and can't change the schema.

Comment: @LeBaton - Who is talking about changing a schema here. I am just stressing the need to look it at from ORM perspective since he is trying to accomplish his task using ORM. If you have a legacy schema you try to fit the db modelling with that of object modelling as much as made possible by the ORM using mappings. "M" stands for mapping in ORM. For the question asked - the join table is kind of insignificant when working using ORM as it is used transparently to maintain relations.